# Why is the connection to S3 via a Gateway Endpoint timing out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
VPC:
  PublicSubnet:
    EC2-Instance
    IGW
    NAT
    Route to IGW
  PrivateSubnet:
    EC2-Instance
    Route to NAT
    Route to S3VPCEndpoint
  S3VPCEndpoint
```

This is the network part of my CFn template:

```yaml
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
      CidrBlock: 10.1.0.0/16

  PublicSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.1.0.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: True
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "Raffael Public Subnet"

  PrivateSubnet:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.1.1.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "Raffael Private Subnet"

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    DependsOn: VPC

  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  PrivateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  PublicRouteToIGW:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: AttachGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId:
        Ref: PublicSubnet
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: PublicRouteTable

  PrivateSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId:
        Ref: PrivateSubnet
      RouteTableId:
        Ref: PrivateRouteTable

  PublicInstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  PrivateInstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt PublicInstanceSecurityGroup.GroupId

  Nat:
     Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
     Properties:
        AllocationId: !GetAtt NatEIP.AllocationId
        SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet

  NatEIP:
     Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
     Properties:
        Domain: vpc

  PrivateRouteToNat:
     Type: AWS::EC2::Route
     Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
        NatGatewayId: !Ref Nat

  S3GatewayEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      RouteTableIds:
        - !Ref PublicRouteTable
        - !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.s3
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

There are two EC2 instances - one in the private and one in the public subnet. These and the relevant Security Groups are set up in a second template.

If I SSH into the private EC2 via the public EC2 I can access S3 from the private subnet. Meaning `aws s3 ls` lists all buckets.

But - this request is apparently going over the NAT. Because if I effectively deactivate it by setting the `DestinationCidrBlock` of its route to `1.2.3.4/32` then `aws s3 ls` is timing out:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError
(<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd86b183828>, 
'Connection to s3.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

So I had a look at [Why can’t I connect to an S3 bucket using a gateway VPC endpoint?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-s3-vpc-endpoint/):

1. DNS settings in your VPC: "DNS resolution" of the VPC is set to "Enabled"
2. Route table settings to Amazon S3: There is a route
3. Security group outbound rules: unrestricted
4. Network ACL rules: unrestricted
5. Gateway VPC endpoint policy: unrestricted
6. S3 bucket policy: I'm testing with `ListBucket`

Any idea what I have to adjust in my template?

Comment: One issue I see is that you are missing required [DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html#gatewayattachment) attribute on EIP on VPCGatewayAttachment. This is most likely not the reason why S3 gateway is not working, but still good practice to have the attribute.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure where you are referring to regarding the DependsOn. The link would mean that I have to place `DependsOn: AttachGateway` into the EC2-Resource (of the public subnet). Is that what you mean? The only EIP here is not related to VPCGatewayAttachment.

Comment: @Marcin I think you are referring to what is inidicated in the last example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-natgateway.html. This example confused me b/c there is no `VPCGatewayAttach` specified and it worked without this `DependsOn` so I just left it out.

Comment: Check example in the link you posted. It has `DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttach` for the EIP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your VPC setup is correct** (minus missing `DependsOn`). I used **copy-and-paste** to replicate your setup, launched two instances, one public and one private, and everything works as expected.

I also removed the NAT gateway, and still s3 access worked in private subnet. To double check I deleted the S3 VPC gateway, and the access to s3 stopped, indicating that the traffic was going through the gateway.

Thus, **there must be something else happening**, not related to the VPC setup. Maybe something with your instances? I used `us-east-1` region though, thus there maybe is some regional issue in `eu-central-1`?

Comment: I will redeploy the stack and give it another try. And thanks a lot for taking the effort to actually test the template!

Comment: @Raffael No problem. Please use the `DependsOn` attribute as its needed when using gateway attachments.

Comment: Is there a strict logic behind when to use `DependsOn` or is it added intuitively according to the underlying DAG? Would it be good practice to just add it basically everywhere where there is a dependency?

Comment: @Raffael The CFN attempts to create resources in parallel. So in case of GatewayAttachment and EIP there is no relationship in terms of `Ref` parameter. So it can happen that EIP will get created a bit before attachment, leading to errors, as it needs it for the IP address. Most other resources are interconnected using `Ref` or `GetAtt`, so CFN can figure out correct order and `DependsOn` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

> Endpoints currently do not support cross-Region requests—ensure that
>   you create your endpoint in the same Region as your bucket. You can
>   find the location of your bucket by using the Amazon S3 console, or by
>   using the get-bucket-location command. Use a Region-specific Amazon S3
>   endpoint to access your bucket; for example,
>   mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com. For more information about
>   Region-specific endpoints for Amazon S3, see Amazon Simple Storage
>   Service (S3) in Amazon Web Services General Reference. If you use the
>   AWS CLI to make requests to Amazon S3, set your default Region to the
>   same Region as your bucket, or use the --region parameter in your
>   requests.

Check if this might be the culprit.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html

Comment: everything is in eu-central-1

Comment: Did you create connection like `boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url='s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com')'`? It might work

Answer (score 0):

#### From your public subnet EC2 instance:

This EC2 instance as a public IPv4 address and can use an Internet Gateway.

```
$ aws s3 ls
```

Should be ok.

```
$ aws s3 ls --region eu-central-1
```

Should be ok.

#### From your private subnet EC2 instance:

This EC2 instance as only private IPv4 address and cannot use the Internet Gateway,
you have created a VPCEndpoint for accessing S3.

```
$ aws s3 ls
```

Is NOT ok (does not respond).

I guess you probably have S3 buckets in multiple regions?

```
$ aws s3 ls --region eu-central-1
```

Should be ok.

**You can only list S3 buckets of the "eu-central-1" region
because your VPC endpoint is associated with the region "eu-central-1".**

You can verify in the AWS console the value created form your CF template:

```
ServiceName: !Sub com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.s3
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the solution was to add `--region <region>` to your AWS CLI command.

e.g.

```bash
aws --region eu-central-1 s3 ls
```